# how do you work out how many bits are needed for the opcode?

Tags: cpu, hardware, instruction-set

There is 16 bits/word, and the instruction set consists of 17 different operations.

I know that there is 5 bits needed for the opcode, but I have no idea why. Why is 5 bits needed for the opcode?

Answer (score 1):

You need 17 different values to represent the 17 different opcodes. For example, with 1 bit, you can represent two (2<sup>1</sup>) different values: 0 and 1. The minimum number of bits to represent 17 different values is 5 because 2<sup>4</sup> is only 16 but 2<sup>5</sup> is 32 (which is >= 17). These calculations are based on a fundamental counting principle called the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

> There is 16 bits/word

This piece of information is irrelevant.